# How can I use Time.at with a specific timezone in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I have a value of `36000` which is stored in a DB column and is the number of seconds since midnight in UTC that in time equals to 11:00.

I want `Time.at(36000).utc` to give me the the value: `1970-01-01 11:00:00 UTC`
but instead I'm getting `1970-01-01 10:00:00 UTC`

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

36000 seconds is 10 hours. Try 39600

Answer (score 0):

Try this little hack `Time.at(36000).utc + 3600` where 3600 is the number of seconds in an hour